# Divide sql query on excel vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to divide a long query here is part of it, when I remove the second line (indicated with !!) everything is ok but when I add, receive error "type mismatch". The reason is the lenght of line cause if I shorten second line and add there is no problem.

This method I use to divide query but receive error cause of line lenght  any idea ?

```
strSqla = "SELECT DT4 .ABH, DT4 .S1 , CASE WHEN S1 = 'AV' OR S1 = 'AN' OR S1 = 'AY' THEN 'PDE' "
' !!!!!!strSqla = strSqla & "WHEN S1 = 'AE' OR S1 = 'AH' OR S1 = 'AK' OR S1 = 'FE' THEN 'EME' "
strSqla = strSqla & "ELSE 'MANUAL' END AS division "
strSqla = strSqla & "FROM H9.PCFILES.DT4 DT4 WHERE DT4 .IDATE > '" & X & "'"
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=PCFILES289;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
   .CommandText = Array(strSqla)
    .RowNumbers = False
```

Answer (score 0):

use line continuators and string concatenation:

```
strSqla = "SELECT DT4 .ABH, DT4 .S1 , CASE WHEN S1 = 'AV' OR " & _
          "S1 = 'AN' OR S1 = 'AY' THEN 'PDE' WHEN S1 = 'AE' OR " & _
          "S1 = 'AH' OR S1 = 'AK' OR S1 = 'FE' THEN 'EME' " & _
          "ELSE 'MANUAL' END AS division FROM H9.PCFILES.DT4 " & _
          "DT4 WHERE DT4 .IDATE > '" & X & "'"
```

Comment: I tried to combine both but still receive error `strSqla = "SELECT DT4.ABALPH, DT4.S1, CASE WHEN S1= 'AV' OR S1= 'AN' OR S1= 'AY' THEN 'XDE' " & _
    "WHEN S1= 'AE' OR S1= 'AH' OR S1= 'AK' OR S1= 'XE' THEN 'XME' "
    strSqla = strSqla & "ELSE 'MANUAL' END AS div "
    strSqla = strSqla & "FROM H9.PCFILE.DT4 DT4 WHERE DT4.IDATE > '" & X & "'"`

Comment: Is that supposed to mean something to me?

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to what `Macro Man` said:

- there's a limit to line continuation at about 20 lines
- after that one has to resort to something like you did

  `strSqla = " .... "
  strSqla = strSqla & " .... "`
- either way, the query construction gets clumsy rather quick, especially if you have single quote `'string-expressions'`

So, should you use longer SQLs frequently and change them occassionally, consider one of the following Alternatives:

A) Storing the SQL in separate textfiles, then read them into a string with a stored function like so:

```
Function fetchSQL(path As String) As String
    Dim Line As String
    Dim iFile As Integer
    iFile = FreeFile
    Open path For Input As #iFile

    Do Until EOF(iFile)
        Line Input #iFile, Line
        fetchSQL = fetchSQL & vbNewLine & Line
    Loop

    Close #iFile
End Function
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
strSqla = fetchSQL("c:\yourpath\p01.sql")
```

B) Alternatively, if you prefer storing your SQL inside your workbook (assuming you use excel), you ofc store the SQL inside a worksheet-column instead and use something like this:

```
Function fetchSQL as String()
    Dim i as Integer
    i = 1
    While Not IsEmpty(yoursheet.Cells(i, 2))
        fetchSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & " " & yoursheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Martin Thank you for your response, I tried second option, get SQL query from cell, but still get "type mismatch" error. I tried; Write all code in one cell, dvide and write in to one cell, divide codes to 2 cell. non of them works :( fetchSQL = this line gives error, without going second line.

Comment: Why are you using `.CommandText = Array(fetchSQL)` instead of  `.CommandText = fetchSQL`? ` Try `Debug.Print (fetchSQL)` for testing to check if your SQL-String looks like you would expect before using it.

Comment: Thank you Martin! now with your correction option 1 is working. But still I have error on option 2 get query from cell. [link](http://i66.tinypic.com/i2klms.jpg)  divided query into cells, write to single cell, add "" or continuations, non of them works [link](http://i67.tinypic.com/8vt94x.jpg)

Comment: elit, I am sorry - I missed your response. AFAIK SQL in Excel doesn't support `CASE` Expressions. Use the [`SWITCH` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) instead and see if it works. Also, for first testing, try a slightly less complex query where you can rule out any syntax errors, like `select top 10 * from yourtable`

Answer (score 0):

Tried second option but still get error type mismatch here are images
[image: cell]

[image: vba]

Answer (score 0):

It worked , for getting sql query from a cell this is the correct codes ;

```
Function fetchSQL() As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 7))
fetchSQL = fetchSQL & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 7).Value & " "
i = i + 1
Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure to A) post your questions by editing your original Post or as comments and B) mark a post as an answer if it solved your problem